# How to make a module as a reusable module in angular?

Tags: angular13, angular-library

I am working on a Angular  13 project. we have different modules in the project and one module name is Intext Module. we need this module as separate project as well as in the existing project along with other modules. so how to make Intext module code reusable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a library in a new bitbucket repository and installed in two projects so that i am able to reuse the comopnents.